# 1&1 Dedicated Linux Server w/ Plesk 10 - How to add PEAR without breaking?

Tags: linux, php, pear, 1and1

I have a 1&1 Dedicated server, running Linux and I use Plesk 10 to administrate (although I do have root access).

It appears to have been configured --without-pear - but I would like to add it (for all current and future sites on the server).

How can I do this without breaking or circumventing the current plesk/php installation?  I didn't want to go ahead and start installing things in case it doesn't work with the way its setup (or worse, breaks it completely).

Any suggestions? I couldn't find an article written in the last 4 years....

Comment: http://trulymanaged.com/blog/enable-pear-php-for-a-domain-on-plesk/

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the OS you have elected to install, you will need to install php-pear onto your system. On Red Hat/CentOS, this is

```
yum install php-pear
```

This will install the pear binary for you.  If you then need specific pear modules, you will need to install them using:

```
pear install "module"
```

Where module is the name of the module.  Don't forget to add the extension to your /etc/php.d/ directory or php.ini.

Be careful when trying to add php-pear to be certain that for some reason the system does not try to change your PHP version.  This should not happen but if other repositories have been configured, it could try to install another version of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

According to this site:

http://mattiasgeniar.be/2008/08/20/how-to-enable-pear-packages-in-plesk/

PEAR should already be installed, just shy. A few vhosts config changes and you're off.

Unless PHP has been compiled without PEAR, then no, its probably never going to work unless you reinstall it, or get your hosting provider to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely presuming the distro is RHEL Centos ... Regardless, you need to have root access to use a package manager (yum, apt, aptitude, synaptic, etc ...) to install php-pear ... However, [here](http://www.smerret.com/computers/linux/control-panels/using-pear-with-plesk) is a fairly straightforward tutorial.